# How to position the box next to other

Tags: html, css

I want to place 2 box in 1 line and the other 2 in the next line but I don't know how to do it,
 now it is only showing 1 box per line,
 Can any of you guys give the solution to this problem please

```css
body{
    background:#f4f4f4;
    color:#555;
    font-family:Bahnschrift SemiCondensed;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0;
}

.container{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#operator {
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.op-box {
    border-radius: 15px / 50px;
    background:#ccc;
    margin:12px; 
    position: relative;
    height:155px;
    width: 50%;
    border:green 1px solid ;
    display:inline-block;
}

.op-box a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    position: absolute;
    padding:70px 0px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
        <h4>list</h4>
            <ul id="operator">
                <li><div class="op-box"><a href="#">list1</a></div></li>
                <li><div class="op-box"><a href="#">list2</a></div></li>
                <li><div class="op-box"><a href="#">list3</a></div></li>
                <li><div class="op-box"><a href="#">list4</a></div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <div style="margin-top:400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to place 2 box in 1 line and the other 2 in the next line but I don't know how to do it,
 now it is only showing 1 box per line,
 Can any of you guys give the solution to this problem please

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide [mcve]

Comment: Try to read flexbox doc or grid doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is to use width and float to align them:

```
.op-box{
  width:40%;
  float:left;
}
```

width can be change to 50% depends on your margin and padding.

Note: If you want to manipulate the first and second items, you can use the :nth-child() select.

Read more here : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by doing something like this:

```
ul {
  display: grid;  
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
```